# Netbeans PHP - I can't see my web server

Tags: php, wordpress, netbeans

I have a wordpress website on my WAMP server, which I made as a project in Netbeans IDE. Everything was working fine untill I changed the name of my PHP project from 'stickpeg' to 'portfolio'. Now when I try to run my project by clicking the green arrow on the menu tab, it displays me a page saying...

Not Found

The requested URL /wordpress/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

I'm thinking that the error is something to do with my NetBeansProjects  folder, as it's not in my wamp folder at all, but in my documents folder! Plus, the project folder in the NetBeansProjects folder is called 'portfolio', which has 3 other folders inside it called config, public_html and test, which are all empty.

Please help, I just want to be able to see my wordpress website running in my browser again.

Comment: Have you set the correct starting file in the project? eg index.php

Comment: @AntB I really don't know. How would I check that the correct starting file is index.php, in netbeans??

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the files in the `htdocs` directory. Apache (e.g. your WAMP server) can't find the files, since there are in the My Documents folder.

Just move the directory `wordpress` to `C:\wamp\htdocs\wordpress` (for example).

Comment: My file directory is 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress'. I take it 'www' and 'htdocs' are the same thing. So my file directory is setup correctly, it's just netbeans not being able to find my files I think because I renamed my project differently.

Comment: Yes, there are the same thing. Are you sure that's the directory in Netbeans as well? What do you mean by the My Documents directory?

 What's the exact URL that's being opened? If you go to http://localhost/wordpress/index.php, does it work? And http://localhost/wordpress/?

Comment: Both localhost/wordpress/index.php and localhost/wordpress do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Sorted it out. Apparently I had to change the Site Address URL and WordPress Address (URL) and then go into netbean's project properties -> run configuration and change the project url.